# Prove that if $n$ is an even natural number and $a>0$, there exists a unique $x>0$ such that $x^{n}=a$

Tags: real-analysis

I got a problem with this exercise:

> Prove that, if $n$ is an even natural number and $a>0$, there exists a unique $x>0$ such that $x^{n}=a$

What is the best way to prove this exercise? I don't know how start this exercise, can anybody give me some ideas, please?

Comment: By `par` you mean *even*?

Comment: No, pair, sorry. i'm from spain. jeje @dxiv

Comment: What does a "pair natural number" mean, then? Does it mean "divisible by $2$"?

Comment: `No, pair` Sorry, there is no such thing as a *pair number*. Google translate suggests that you mean "número par" which in English is "even number". Is that right?

Comment: yes sorry! @dxiv

Comment: The hypothesis that $n$ is even is irrelevant, as the property is also true for odd $n$. It's difficult to give "the best way” without knowing in what context you are: do you know about derivatives and the intermediate value theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from the fact that $f(x)=x^n$ is injective for $x>0$ and surjective in $[0, +\infty)$. You can prove it showing that its derivative for the positive real is always positive (and vanish only in 0, which is a minimum), and this gives the injectivity. The surjectivity follows from the limits in $0$ and $+\infty$.

Comment: But how do you _prove_ that $x\to x^n$ is bijective on the positive reals? That's what this problem is about, I think. It's just not formulated exactly that way.

Comment: You can prove it showing that its derivative for the positive real is always positive (and vanish only in 0, which is a minimum), and this gives the injectivity. The surjectivity follows from the limits in $0$ and $+\infty$.

Comment: I can add it in the answer.

Comment: In order to prove that x^n is surjective onto [0,$\infty), Giuseppe, you have to prove that for every y>0, there is an nth root of y; effectively assuming the fact that the OP is trying to prove.

Comment: @AdamV.Nease Surjectivity also follows from the "*limits at 0 and infinity*" given that the function is continuous, but indeed that point should be better emphasized in the answer.

Comment: Yes, but at the point in introductory analysis where they are expected to prove the existence of nth roots, they have not done anything with continuity nor derivatives which are your and Giuseppe's approaches.

Comment: The existence can be proven directly from the least upper bound axiom. I'll get to work on it now. That's what the original poster's professor wants anyway.

Comment: @AdamV.Nease `they have not done anything with continuity nor derivatives which are your and Giuseppe's approaches` It is not *my* approach at all, I was just explaining Giuseppe's (presumed) line of thought. As for whether the OP knows anything about continuity and derivates, that's something none of us can guess at this point. The question of `in what context you are` has been asked in a comment already, but was not answered yet.